# JQuery - Creating parent grandparent level text as object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create previous parent and grandparent level text as object using function

For example on element grandchild11

```
<a class="level-12" href="#" parobj="['Child1','Child','Grandparent']" other="getOther(this)"> Grandchild11</a>
```

I am facing issue in creating object for attribute parobj as shown above for every anchor tag and I have even tried adding class with levels but failing to get exact output

is there anyway to get parobj as mentioned above either by hover or clicking anchor tag?

Codepen URL for reference:
http://codepen.io/divyar34/pen/bqMaQY

HTML:

```js
$('a').attr('parObj', 'getParent(this)'); //adding attr parentObject with function to get parent,grandparent details
$('a').attr('other', 'getOther(this)'); //other Info attribute for ajax call

function getParent(val) {
  var obj = [val];
  obj.push($(val).parent().text());
  return obj
}

function getOther(val) {
  //just for reference, but originaly using internal api
  $.get('otherinfo.html', {
    option: val
  }, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    return data.name
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="level-1">Parent1
  <ul class="level-2">
    <li class="level-3"><a class="level-4" href="#">Grandparent</a>
      <div class="level-4">
        <ul class="level-5">
          <li class="level-6">
            <a class="level-7" href="#">Child</a>
            <div class="level-7">
              <ul class="level-8">
                <li class="level-9"> <a class="level-10" href="#">Child1</a>
                  <ul class="level-10">
                    <li class="level-11"><a class="level-12" href="#"> Grandchild11</a></li>
                    <li class="level-11"><a class="level-12" href="#"> Grandchild11</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="level-9"> <a class="level-10" href="#">Child2</a>
                  <ul class="level-10">
                    <li class="level-11"><a class="level-12" href="#">GrandChild21</a></li>
                    <li class="level-11"><a class="level-12" href="#">grandchild22</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="level-6">
            <a class="level-7" href="#"> Child2 </a>
            <ul class="level-7">
              <li class="level-8"><a class="level-9" href="#">GrandChild21</a></li>
              <li class="level-8"><a class="level-9" href="#">grandchild22</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- Parent1 -->

<div class="level-1">Parent2
  <ul class="level-2">
    <li class="level-3"><a class="level-4" href="#">Grandparent</a>
      <div class="level-4">
        <ul class="level-5">
          <li class="level-6">
            <a class="level-7" href="#">Child</a>
            <div class="level-7">
              <ul class="level-8">
                <li class="level-7"> <a class="level-8" href="#">Child1</a>
                  <ul class="level-8">
                    <li class="level-9"><a class="level-10" href="#"> Grandchild11</a></li>
                    <li class="level-9"><a class="level-10" href="#"> Grandchild11</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="level-7"> <a class="level-8" href="#">Child2</a>
                  <ul class="level-8">
                    <li class="level-9"><a class="level-10" href="#">GrandChild21</a></li>
                    <li class="level-9"><a class="level-10" href="#">grandchild22</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="level-6">
            <a class="level-7" href="#"> Child2 </a>
            <ul class="level-7">
              <li class="level-8"><a class="level-9" href="#">GrandChild21</a></li>
              <li class="level-8"><a class="level-9" href="#">grandchild22</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- Parent2 -->
```

Comment: you can save JavaScript object as attribute if you convert those as strings first https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify then you can convert those back to objects using JSON.parse function https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Comment: @jyrkim, I even tried o get that parobj onhover and click but no luck :(